# jquery ideal forms not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone Please help me in using this plugin? I have gone through the documentation and the code is best to my knowledge. Can anybody tell me what's wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->


<head>
<title>Test Ideal Form</title>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.idealforms.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.idealforms.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var $myform = $('#my-form').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
</script>
  <h1>My Test Form</h1>
<form id="my-form">
  <div><label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" data-ideal="required username"/></div>
  <div><label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" data-ideal="required password"/></div>
  <div><label>E-Mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" data-ideal="required email"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try replacing:

```
var $myform = $('#my-form').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
```

#### With:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-form').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
});
```

And let us know! Also, move the `<script>` tag inside the `<head>`.

---

#### Or another option:

Move the `<script>` tag before the `</body>`:

```
    ....
    <script>
      var $myform = $('#my-form').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Praveen, It does not make any change.

Comment: Okay, can you confirm that the files are present?

Comment: @Hackopedia: I'm the developer of Ideal Forms and this should work by looking at your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->


<head>
<title>Test Ideal Form</title>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.idealforms.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.idealforms.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>My Test Form</h1>
<form id="my-form">
  <div><label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" data-ideal="required username"/></div>
  <div><label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" data-ideal="required password"/></div>
  <div><label>E-Mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" data-ideal="required email"/></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').idealforms();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also check this
http://code.google.com/p/idealforms/wiki/MiniHowTo